# Java replay when certain character typed

Tags: java

When number 0 is typed after the guess is correct, it should replay the game.  It just returns the message "0 to play again and 1 to quit"

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean game = true; //true means the game will continue playing, false stops the game
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess: ");
    while (game) {
        HiLo mainGame = new HiLo();
        mainGame.generateRandomNumber();
        boolean guessCorrect = false;
        while (!guessCorrect) {
            int inputted = input.nextInt();
            if (inputted == 101) {
                guessCorrect = true;
                System.out.println("quitted");
            }
            System.out.println(mainGame.checkGuess(inputted));
            mainGame.getGuessCounter();
            if (mainGame.checkGuess(inputted) == "Correct! You got it right!") {
                guessCorrect = true;
                System.out.println("Correct after " + mainGame.getGuessCounter() + " guesses");
            }
        }
        while (guessCorrect = true) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (0 : YES) (1 : NO)");
            System.out.println("Your answer: ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            //issues with inputting 0 and restarting game
            if (answer == 0) {
                game = true;
            }
            else if (answer == 1) {
                guessCorrect = true;
                System.out.println("Game Over");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error, can't understand the meaning"); 
                guessCorrect = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (guessCorrect = true)` That should be just `while (guessCorrect)`

Comment: `if (mainGame.checkGuess(inputted) == "Correct! You got it right!")` I couldn't find the code for method `checkGuess` but I assume it returns a string. Please refer to [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Change `while (guessCorrect = true)` to `while (guessCorrect)`. Set `guessCorrect` to `false` to exit the `while (guessCorrect)` loop and proceed to restarting or exiting the game. Make sure to set the `game` to `false` if `answer` is not equal to `0` to exit the game.

```java
        while (guessCorrect) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (0 : YES) (1 : NO)");
            System.out.println("Your answer: ");
            int answer = input.nextInt();
            //issues with inputting 0 and restarting game
            if (answer == 0) {
                game = true;
            }
            else if (answer == 1) {
                System.out.println("Game Over");
                game = false;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error, can't understand the meaning"); 
                game = false;
            }
            
            guessCorrect = false;
        }
```